# Convert MYSQL Query to Eloquent

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

How do I convert this query to Eloquent syntax

```
    SELECT x.id, x.title, points, (points - 1)/POW(((UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW()) - UNIX_TIMESTAMP(x.created_at))/3600)+2, 1.5) as hasil
    FROM media x
    JOIN (SELECT m.id, 
                 (SUM(mp.up)-SUM(mp.down)) AS points
            FROM media m
            JOIN media_points mp ON mp.media_id = m.id
        GROUP BY m.id) y ON y.id = x.id
ORDER BY hasil DESC
   LIMIT 100
```

Comment: Please understand that no one here is doing the work for you. Show what you already have done and where your problems are in detail. And keep in mind, that not every SQL statement can be converted to an Eloquent syntax. For complex SQL statements `raw()` sql will still be the way to go.

Comment: thanks for your advice by using raw.
finally i found the answer

Media::select(DB::raw('media.*, (points - 1)/POW(((UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW()) - UNIX_TIMESTAMP(media.created_at))/3600)+2, 1.5) as hasil'))
        ->join(DB::raw('(SELECT m.id, (SUM(mp.up)-SUM(mp.down)) AS points FROM media m JOIN media_points mp ON mp.media_id = m.id GROUP BY m.id) as T'), 'T.id', '=', 'media.id')
        ->orderBy('hasil','desc')
        ->take(100)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally i found the answer by using raw()

```
Media::select(DB::raw('media.*, (points - 1)/POW(((UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW()) - UNIX_TIMESTAMP(media.created_at))/3600)+2, 1.5) as hasil'))
                                ->join(DB::raw('(SELECT m.id, (SUM(mp.up)-SUM(mp.down)) AS points FROM media m JOIN media_points mp ON mp.media_id = m.id GROUP BY m.id) as T'), 'T.id', '=', 'media.id')
                                ->orderBy('hasil','desc')
                                ->take(100)
```